# Calculation in SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table containing a field called ChannelId. I want to break it out into two fields depending on the value. I tried this:

```
SELECT CustomerId, ChannelId = 1 as Chan1, ChannelId = 2 as Chan2 FROM ....
```

The goal being that I have two boolean columns representing whether the ChannelId field is of the approriate value. I get a syntax error.

Looking at the SQL Syntax I can't see any reason why I can't use an expression and then alias it as a new column name, but SQL Server croaked on it. Am I doing something really dumb? How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If there are only two values in the column why not just return the values as the columns? Are you wanting to perform some aggregate on the column? like say count how many times each value is present?

Comment: No, reformatting the data for input to a different process.

Comment: I think you need to create two loose queries (or by subqueries). The trick of SQL is not to ask things in the `SELECT` part, but in the `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform an expression, not an assignment, and it depends on he flavor of SQL. Since you're using SQL Server (T-SQL):

```
SELECT CustomerId, (CASE WHEN ChannelId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Chan1, (CASE WHEN ChannelId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Chan2 FROM ....
```

There might be a better way to do it, but that's how I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select
    CustomerId
  , case when ChannelId = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Channel_1
  , case when ChannelId = 2 then 1 else 0 end as Channel_2
from Customer_Channel ;
```

Answer (score 0):

People have already said how to do this, using a `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN` style statement, but I'd just like to offer the opinion that this amounts to having business logic in the database.  Typically I aim to keep the database purely for storage, and have business logic in a higher layer of my application.

I think this way because if you consider an application to have a layered architecture, you'd put your business logic in one layer, and one or more layers deeper would be your database.  One or more layers higher would be your UI.  "Business logic in the database" is bad in the same way it'd be bad to put business logic in the handler for a `button_Click` event on a form.

I appreciate this might not be appropriate for your particular circumstances on this day in 2011, but for future readers of this question, I hope it's of some use.

Comment: "business logic in the database" can you explain why that's bad

Comment: If you consider an application to have a layered architecture, you'd put your business logic in one layer, and one or more layers deeper would be your database.  One or more layers higher would be your UI.  It's bad in the same way it'd be bad to put business logic in the handler for a `button_Click` event on a form.

Comment: Whatever you can put in the lowest layer is pure benefit. I never worked with 3 tier architecture, but with 2 tier (client-server) I would put as much business logic as I can in the back-end. It means safer, faster apps.

Comment: @Neil I'm really trying not be a jerk, but why is putting business logic in a button_click bad. What makes it "better" to put it elsewhere. Also what constitutes business logic.

Comment: This looks like it's about to explode into a typical religious debate about tiers and business logic. When the luminaries of the field have recommendations all over the map, it's probably better to think about it, pick one, and be consistent within a project, while heavily documenting any breaks from it, than to tell everyone exactly what they should do.

Comment: @SilverbackNet You're right I apologize for feeding this. I'll stop now

Comment: Yes I'm stopping this here.  You can do whatever you want - there are no rules, only recommendations.  It feels nice and elegant to me to put all the rules defined by the business (i.e. if a value is between x and y return true else return false) in a "business logic layer" in my app, so it can be re-used, and so the app is db-agnostic etc.

Comment: @SilverbackNet Also I disagree that the "luminaries" are all over the map.  There's a very strong consensus in this area, though most people won't tell you what you you *have* to do because there are too many unknowns.  If you're writing a test harness app that'll be used once by one support technician for a product upgrade, then all this layering stuff probably isn't necessary.  If you're writing enterprise-grade software that'll run a large company for many years and through many upgrades, it probably is.